# Quitar datos en vacio

Tags: javascript

Quisiera quitar vacios y espacios en blanco en un array que obtengo desde google sheet y se imprimen de esta manere:

```
var prueba = ['NOV-DIC 17','ENE-FEB 18','MAR-ABR 18','MAY-JUN 18','JUL-AGO 
18','SEP-OCT 18','NOV-DIC 18','   ','  ','',''];
```

Como pueden notar hay tanto vacíos como espacios en blanco luego de eso lo formateo con un join y queda así:

```
NOV-DIC 17,ENE-FEB 18,MAR-ABR 18,MAY-JUN 18,,,, ,
```

Pero lo que realmente necesito es que me imprima esto:

```
NOV-DIC 17,ENE-FEB 18,MAR-ABR 18,MAY-JUN 18
```

sin las ultimas comas

Comment: tenes algun codigo hecho? en javascript nativo o jquery?

Comment: Realmente el codigo proviene de una herramienta que se llama Ultradox y utiluiza un editor JS dentro con el cual me permite interactuar con la herramienta: 

`var prueba = [${foreach rows rowsEntry ',}'${rowsEntry.storeAudit}${end}']; 

var bdg = prueba.join();

var abc = [prueba.filter(Boolean)];


// Return output variables
var result = {
  'abc' : abc,
  'bdg' : bdg
};
result;`

Comment: Si recorres el array en busca de lo qe este vacio y lo eliminas del mismo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pica la cadena luego de las dos comas seguidas, te quedaria asi:

```js
var cadena = 'NOV-DIC 17,ENE-FEB 18,MAR-ABR 18,MAY-JUN 18,,,'
var cadenaCortada = cadena.split(',,')[0]
console.log(cadenaCortada)
```

Comment: Gracias con el split me funciono

Comment: si te soluciono el problema, y si puedes marca la respuesta como correcta para que evites mas respuestas con lo mismo, saludos

Comment: Ya lo hices, una pregunta sabes como formateo esos datos en una sola variable?, me explico: cuando obtengo los datos utilizo un .join() para quitar las comillas y dejarle solo las comas y luego tendria que utilizar otra linea de codigo para utilizar el .split me gustaria dejar todo en una misma variable

`var prueba = [${foreach rows rowsEntry ',}'${rowsEntry.storeAudit}${end}']; 

var bdg = prueba.join();

var abc = bdg.split(',,')[0];


// Return output variables
var result = {
  'abc' : abc,
  'bdg' : bdg
};
result;`

Comment: así `var bdg = prueba.join().split(',,')[0]` , tendrías el resultado final en **bdg**, dime si te funciono

Comment: Si, muchas gracias, si me funcionó

Answer (score 3):

Posiblemente la forma más sencilla sea utilizar el método `filter` del objeto `Array` para coger los elementos que no están compuestos únicamente por espacios vacíos:

```js
var prueba = ['NOV-DIC 17','ENE-FEB 18','MAR-ABR 18','MAY-JUN 18','JUL-AGO 18','SEP-OCT 18','NOV-DIC 18','   ','  ','',''];

var sinvacios = prueba.filter(e => e.trim() !== '');

console.log(sinvacios.join());
```

Answer (score 1):

Antes de imprimir puedes eliminarlos sin recorrerlos o agregar solo los que tienen contenido en un nuevo array, como...

```js
function limpiarArray(actual) {
  var newArray = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < actual.length; i++) {
    if (actual[i]) {
      newArray.push(actual[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
let arrLimpio = limpiarArray([1, 2,, 3,, 3,,,,,, 4,, 4,, 5,, 6,,,,]);
console.log(arrLimpio);
```

Answer (score 0):

Con el `Array.filter` solucionas lo que quieres hacer

```js
var prueba = ['NOV-DIC 17','ENE-FEB 18','MAR-ABR 18','MAY-JUN 18','JUL-AGO 18','SEP-OCT 18','NOV-DIC 18','   ','  ','','']

prueba = prueba.filter(element => {
  element = element.replace(/ /g,'')
  if (element !== '')
   return element
})

console.log(prueba)
```